# disk quota exceeded but there is space

Tags: linux, quota

I am getting 'disk quota exceeded' error but the partition is not full and user has unlimited quota. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

```
xxx@mc:/tmp$ pyenv install 3.7.6
/home/xxx/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 2048: cannot create temp file for here-document: Disk quota exceeded
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/python-build.20220629235336.143991’: Disk quota exceeded

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220629235336.143991

xxx@mc:/tmp$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            445M     0  445M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M 1016K   97M   2% /run
/dev/sda         19G   11G  7.5G  58% /
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc        4.8G   20M  4.7G   1% /baks
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/0


xxx@mc:/tmp$ quota -u
Disk quotas for user xxx (uid 1000): none
```

Comment: Are there group quotas in effect? Check with `quota -g`.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The point of quotas is to avoid running out of disk space, so it makes sense that they restrict disk usage *before* the disk is full.

Quotas can be set on users, but they can also be used to limit the collective storage space used by a group of users.

In your case, you show that there is no user quota in effect.

Group quotas are viewed with `quota -g`, and [according to comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708071/disk-quota-exceeded-but-there-is-space?noredirect=1#comment1340494_708071), this seems to be what's causing your issue.  It's additionally slightly odd that the `/tmp` directory is not its own `tmpfs` filesystem on the system you're connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue. 'quota -su; df /tmp' confirms that I am hitting user quota in /tmp and it is not full, but 'find /tmp -user $USER' comes up empty, and 'quota -sg | grep < tmp mount >' finds no group quota involved. So I don't know why the system says my tmp quota is exceeded.

I found a work-around: change the location of my bash temp files.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp
$ export TMPDIR=~/tmp
$ echo "export TMPDIR=~/tmp" >> ~/.bashrc
```